# why is this invalid? PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the code you see below. I am really new at php and I don't know why this is wrong.  I'm not sure I understand it very well.

Please can you help me to figure out the failure.

The failure says:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

in...

```html
       <ul class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-1-1 ">
    
            <?php foreach(wpjb_get_categories() as $ja): ?>
      <li>
           
 <?php if(isset($param["category"]) && in_array($ja->id, (array)$param["category"])): ?>  <?php endif; ?> 
 

 
<label for="<?php esc_attr_e("wpjb-search-".$ja->id) ?>"><?php esc_html_e($ja->title) ?></label>
                
           
                                
        <?php  foreach($result->job as $job): ?>
        <?php /* @var $job Wpjb_Model_Job */ ?>
        <?php $this->job = $job; ?>
        <?php $this->render("index-item.php") ?>
        
        <?php endforeach; ?>
       
       
             
      </li>
           
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            
   </ul>
```

Comment: Can you post a var_dump of $result ?

Comment: Where have you declared and assigned value to `$result`?

Comment: What is wpjb_get_categories() ?

Comment: i thin $result is is declared nowhere. the vardump is 0. 
wpjb_get_categories()  are the job categorys

Answer (score 2):

Only one possible answer, one of your parameters to the foreaches is not an iterable array.

Comment: ok i understand this but i still have no clue how to fix. I want this result.

-category 1/
job1 of category1/
job2 of category1/
job2 of category1/


-category 2/
job1 of category2/
job2 of category2/
job2 of category2/

Comment: The question is "Why is this invalid?"